# How to get paginated data from API in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

Let's say we have this endpoint `https://reqres.in/api/users`.

The response is

```
{
    "page": 1,
    "per_page": 3,
    "total": 12,
    "total_pages": 4,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "first_name": "George",
            "last_name": "Bluth",
            "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "first_name": "Janet",
            "last_name": "Weaver",
            "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "first_name": "Emma",
            "last_name": "Wong",
            "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/olegpogodaev/128.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the result in PowerBI

[image]

So my questions are :

- How can I play with the content of `data`, instead of showing the string `"[List]"` only?
- Can PowerBI  handle the pagination? Can it change the `page` param? `?page=X`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> How can I play with the content of data, instead of showing the string
>   "[List]" only?

Power BI actually provides a user-friendly UI to navigate and construct the query, so you can just click on the links/buttons to expand and drill down the query and get the data you want:

Click `List`:

[image: list]

Convert to table:

[image: convert to table]

Expand the column:

[image: expand the column]

Results:
[image: results]

Which is equivalent to the following M / Power Query (`Query -> Advanced Editor`):

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://reqres.in/api/users")),
    data = Source[data],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(data, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"id", "first_name", "last_name", "avatar"}, {"id", "first_name", "last_name", "avatar"})
in
    #"Expanded Column1"
```

---

> Can PowerBI handle the pagination? Can it change the page param?
>   ?page=X

Yes. You can actually convert the above query to a function, and pass it the page number to get the data for each page.

First you can get the `total_pages` from the above query:

Right click `total_pages`, `Add as New query`:
[image: add as new query]

You'll see the following query in the `Query Editor`:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://reqres.in/api/users")),
    total_pages1 = Source[total_pages]
in
    total_pages1
```

Change the last line to generate a list of numbers:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://reqres.in/api/users")),
    List = {1..Source[total_pages]}
in
    List
```

Convert it to table:
[image: convert to table]

Now for the original query, you can add `() =>` before the query to convert it to a function, and pass it the parameter (The API endpoint needs to be changed as well for pagination):

```
(page as text) =>
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=" & page)),
    data = Source[data],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(data, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"id", "first_name", "last_name", "avatar"}, {"id", "first_name", "last_name", "avatar"})
in
    #"Expanded Column1"
```

[image: function]

Rename the function to getPage for better understanding:

[image: getPage]

Now back to the `total_pages` table. Change the `Column1` to text so that it can be passed to `getPage` later:
[image: text]

Then `Invoke Custom Function` and call the `getPage` with `Column1`:

[image: invoke]

[image: invoked]

You'll see a list of table alongside:

[image: tables]

Expand it and you'll see all pages of data in one table:

[image: all data]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Woow thank you! What a complete answer. Imma take a look at it and let you know

Comment: @David Glad it helps!

Comment: @FoxanNg, don't suppose you would know how to do this via Azure API? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48771173/power-bi-call-azure-api-with-nextlink-next-page

Comment: @Beefcake Just have time to take a look at it but I see that you've already got a nicely done solution :)

Comment: Does anyone know how you would change this flow if you didn't know the total number of pages, but a paginated request returned an 'offset' value to use in the subsequent request? (until there were no more pages left).

Comment: This help me a lot..Nice!!

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar, but when I click List in the query editor, nothing happens... I don't see what's in the image at the top of this answer. Can anyone help?

Comment: @nabrown If I understand correclty, instead of pages, you´re getting the amount of results.

For that, in the List = {1..Source[total_pages]} step, you need to generate the offset values. For that, i used List.Generate(()=>0, each _ <= Source[total_results], each _ +50), which creates an "array" of values, starting at 0 and continuing with 50, 100... until the max results. Not sure if this helped or is clear enough.