# Paginated data from API in Power BI-same data repeated for every page

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have referred to solution provided here:

[How to get paginated data from API in Power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904641/how-to-get-paginated-data-from-api-in-power-bi/46909163#46909163?newreg=165bca9b75644f16a681acc0676c2c51)

But problem is same data that is in page 1 is getting repeated for every page
Example: Page 1 we 106 rows page 2 same 106 rows page 3 same 106 getting repeated instead starting from row 107 on page 2.

Would appreciate if anyone can help me to resolve this.

Comment: Can you show us your M query?

Comment: Here is the M Query of function and total pages

Comment: Get Page M Query (truncated query)
-----------------
(page as text) =>
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://abcenterprises.thefutureis.mobi/1/devices/business_devices", [Headers=[#"API-Token"="xxxxxxxxxxxx"]])),
#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromRecords({Source}),
    #"Expanded response" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Converted to Table", "response"),
    #"Expanded response1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded response", "response", {"id", "ref_device_id", "business_id", "esn", "meid", "imei", "msn", "status", "created_at", "updated_at"})

Comment: Total_Pages
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://abcenterprises.thefutureis.mobi/1/devices/business_devices", [Headers=[#"API-Token"="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]])),
    pagination = Source[pagination],
    List = {1..pagination[pages]},
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(List, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error), #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Converted to Table",{{"Column1", type text}}), #"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Data", each getpage_devices([Column1])),
#"Expanded Data"=Table.ExpandTableColumn