# Powerbi API get all data instead of 20 max

Tags: powerbi

I'm new with API data so I struggle a lot with this problem.
When I load data from the web site its stops by 20 (newest) records instead of all the records in one table. When I want to make a report I want all the data and not just 20.

This is the code in advanced editor.

```
Data 1 (sales):

let
    Bron = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://app.website.nl/api/user/v1/account/sales", [Headers=[Accept="application/json", Authorization="Bearer 123456789"]])),
    data = Bron[data],
    #"Geconverteerd naar tabel" = Record.ToTable(data),
    Value = #"Geconverteerd naar tabel"{12}[Value],
    #"Geconverteerd naar tabel1" = Table.FromList(Value, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Column1 uitgevouwen" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Geconverteerd naar tabel1", "Column1", {"id", "user_id", "type", "sub_type", "offer", "offer_accepted", "status", "verification", "verified", "flow_id", "product_id", "incoming_id", "created_at", "finalized_at", "updated_at", "outgoing_at", "offer_answered_at", "verified_at", "valid_till", "cancelled_at", "status_remark", "cancelled_remark", "user_firstname", "user_lastname", "user_email", "organisation_name", "organisation_identifier", "gender", "firstname", "lastname", "business", "company_name", "source", "source_id", "postcode", "housenumber", "streetname", "city", "birthdate", "phone", "email", "iban", "connection_postcode", "connection_housenumber", "connection_streetname", "connection_city", "product_name", "product_identifier", "supplier_name"}, {"id", "user_id", "type", "sub_type", "offer", "offer_accepted", "status", "verification", "verified", "flow_id", "product_id", "incoming_id", "created_at", "finalized_at", "updated_at", "outgoing_at", "offer_answered_at", "verified_at", "valid_till", "cancelled_at", "status_remark", "cancelled_remark", "user_firstname", "user_lastname", "user_email", "organisation_name", "organisation_identifier", "gender", "firstname", "lastname", "business", "company_name", "source", "source_id", "postcode", "housenumber", "streetname", "city", "birthdate", "phone", "email", "iban", "connection_postcode", "connection_housenumber", "connection_streetname", "connection_city", "product_name", "product_identifier", "supplier_name"})
in
    #"Column1 uitgevouwen"

Data 2 (Leads):

let
    Bron = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://app.website.nl/api/user/v1/account/leads", [Headers=[Accept="application/json", Authorization="Bearer 123456789"]])),
    #"Geconverteerd naar tabel" = Table.FromRecords({Bron}),
    #"data uitgevouwen" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Geconverteerd naar tabel", "data", {"path", "per_page", "next_cursor", "next_page_url", "prev_cursor", "prev_page_url", "data"}, {"data.path", "data.per_page", "data.next_cursor", "data.next_page_url", "data.prev_cursor", "data.prev_page_url", "data.data"}),
    #"data.data uitgevouwen" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"data uitgevouwen", "data.data"),
    #"data.data uitgevouwen1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"data.data uitgevouwen", "data.data", {"id", "business", "gender", "firstname", "lastname", "postcode", "housenumber", "suffix", "streetname", "city", "company_name", "activity", "locked", "status", "created_by", "planned_user_id", "planned_date", "planned_by", "planned_at", "planned_from", "planned_to", "completed_at", "created_at", "updated_at", "planned_to_username", "completed_by_username", "lead_source", "filter_status", "name", "address"}, {"data.data.id", "data.data.business", "data.data.gender", "data.data.firstname", "data.data.lastname", "data.data.postcode", "data.data.housenumber", "data.data.suffix", "data.data.streetname", "data.data.city", "data.data.company_name", "data.data.activity", "data.data.locked", "data.data.status", "data.data.created_by", "data.data.planned_user_id", "data.data.planned_date", "data.data.planned_by", "data.data.planned_at", "data.data.planned_from", "data.data.planned_to", "data.data.completed_at", "data.data.created_at", "data.data.updated_at", "data.data.planned_to_username", "data.data.completed_by_username", "data.data.lead_source", "data.data.filter_status", "data.data.name", "data.data.address"}),
    #"Type gewijzigd" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"data.data uitgevouwen1",{{"success", type logical}, {"data.path", type text}, {"data.per_page", Int64.Type}, {"data.next_cursor", type text}, {"data.next_page_url", type text}, {"data.prev_cursor", type any}, {"data.prev_page_url", type any}, {"data.data.id", Int64.Type}, {"data.data.business", Int64.Type}, {"data.data.gender", type text}, {"data.data.firstname", type any}, {"data.data.lastname", type text}, {"data.data.postcode", type text}, {"data.data.housenumber", Int64.Type}, {"data.data.suffix", type any}, {"data.data.streetname", type text}, {"data.data.city", type text}, {"data.data.company_name", type any}, {"data.data.activity", type text}, {"data.data.locked", Int64.Type}, {"data.data.status", type text}, {"data.data.created_by", Int64.Type}, {"data.data.planned_user_id", Int64.Type}, {"data.data.planned_date", type datetime}, {"data.data.planned_by", Int64.Type}, {"data.data.planned_at", type datetime}, {"data.data.planned_from", type datetime}, {"data.data.planned_to", type any}, {"data.data.completed_at", type datetime}, {"data.data.created_at", type datetime}, {"data.data.updated_at", type datetime}, {"data.data.planned_to_username", type text}, {"data.data.completed_by_username", type text}, {"data.data.lead_source", type any}, {"data.data.filter_status", type text}, {"data.data.name", type text}, {"data.data.address", type text}, {"message", type text}})
in
    #"Type gewijzigd"
```

I searched a lot but didn't find a solution.

Comment: This question isn't about Power BI, but the API you are using.

Comment: Please read the description of the tag [api] which states: "do not use this tag".

Answer (score 0):

Check the api first, it maybe limiting to 20. Use POSTMan or similar tool (https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/boomerang-soap-rest-c/bhmdjpobkcdcompmlhiigoidknlgghfo) to query an api.

Check the API documentation to how to get all records or how to page to the next page etc...

Comment: The max is indeed 20, but why? Next question is how to pull all the data from all pages.

Comment: It is possible and it does depend on the API and how it specifies pagination/pages.
Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904641/how-to-get-paginated-data-from-api-in-power-bi
Do check the API documentation, some may have a max items parameter for example.

Comment: When I use the following code: = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://app.website.nl/api/test/v1/account/leads", [Headers=[Accept="application/json", Authorization="Bearer 123456789"]])), I get success = TRUE, data = Record and message = Leads retrieved successfully. I don't see total_pages in the query.